# Freeze on 14.04 installation: graphic issues with Nouveau (Nvidia Geforce 6100)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on an older PC. Installation always freezes at a certain point as well as live cd running (at first just small glitches then hangs completely). Reason for that are graphic issues with a Nvidia Geforce 6100.

What I already tried:

- Trying to install with Setting **acpi=off** and/or **nomodeset** in BootsOptions
- Deactivated Nouveau driver at BootsOptions with **disablemodules=nouveau**
- Installing Nvidia proprietary drivers with adding **ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa** and installing **nvidia-current** (or in my case nvidia-304) in live mode but this always fails because of IO Error not enough space (probably running out of RAM?)

What other options do I have? Is there a way to include the Nvidia driver to a image? Why does VESA mode not work or is setting disablemodules=nouveau not enough?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: run `df -h` please, and post the result.

Comment: probably is running out of ram but it doesn't matter because even if you were to install nvidia drivers on a live cd (which can be done using apt-get **without** the edgers ppa btw) they wouldn't start working until you  reboot anyhow. If you are running out of ram, you can use the ubuntu mini.iso from here. It is an install session only and no live session, only to install but uses significantly less ram: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the following instructions for linux mint (a ubuntu-derivate):
http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_qiana_mate.php

> Solving freezes with some NVIDIA GeForce GPUs
>
> If you are unable to boot Linux Mint with an NVIDIA card, or if you
>   are experiencing constant freezes and system lock ups, please append
>   "nomodeset" to your boot arguments. At the boot menu of the live
>   DVD/USB, press Tab to edit the boot arguments and add "nomodeset" at
>   the end of the line.
>
> If you're still having issues, you can also remove "quiet splash --"
>   from that same line.
>
> Alternatively you can use the "nouveau.noaccel=1" boot argument.
>
> Once the system is installed, use the Driver Manager to install the
>   nvidia-304 driver.

Comment: In my case, adding `nouveau.modeset=0` was the clue.